# How to write lines in python to a list

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x

As of above, I can't find any other sources that would provide a working solution. Basically I want to take strings in a text file with this stored:

```
0
1
2
3
2
4
```

And store the numbers into a list of integers like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
```

Any help?

Comment: Why don't you post what code you have and we'll help you improve it.

Comment: "I can't find any other sources that would provide a working solution" I really find that hard to believe..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file using `open()` and convert into a list like so:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
    int_list = [int(l.strip()) for l in myfile]
```

This iterates over every line, strips the `\n` at the end, converts into an `int`, and puts it all into a list.